# Java waiting for a variable before executing a Callable

Tags: java, multithreading, jdbc

I am connecting to a database, I am using threads and I only want one connection to be active at a time. I was trying to do that like this:

```
public class Database {
    public static Boolean activeConnection = false;

    public static synchronized Connection createConnection() throws SQLException {
        activeConnection = true;

        String url;
        String username;
        String password;
        try {
            String path = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("").getPath()
                    + "application.properties";
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.load(new FileInputStream(path));

            url = properties.getProperty("url");
            username = properties.getProperty("username");
            password = properties.getProperty("password");

            return DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        } catch (IOException | SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new SQLException();
        }
    }
}
```

Now inside my Data fetching Callable I want to only create a connection if there already isn't an active connection... How do I do that? Please note that in this example it will always be false anyways, but I have other threads for fetching other data which may set the activeConnection flag to true.

```
public class FindState implements Callable<List<State>> {
    @Override
    public List<State> call() {
        List<State> states = new ArrayList<>();

        // Wait until Database.activeConnection is false here

        try (Connection con = Database.createConnection();
             ResultSet rs = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM STATE").executeQuery()) {

            while (rs.next()) {
                Long id = rs.getLong("id");
                String name = rs.getString("name");

                states.add(new State(id, name));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return states;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should change `activeConnection` to `boolean` and also make it `volatile`, both save lots of headaches

Comment: The easiest way to wait something and then continue is to use CountDownLatch. Share a reference to the latch between threads and make await() in the waiting thread and countDown() in the starting/initiating thread.